# Grabbing the current image clicked on src attr using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to get the current image selected src value.

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {     
          $('#imagefiles ul li img').click(function() {
              var img = $this.attr('src');
                  alert(img);
          });
      });
</script>
```

When I click on the image it says cannot find the variable `$this`.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)`, not `$this` to get your element wrapped as a jQuery object.

Comment: wow that was quick. i was coming back to delete the question cause i just figured it out. But thank you destroy:)

Answer (score 0):

Try $(this) not $this.

```
$('#imagefiles ul li img').click(function() { 
  var img = $(this).attr('src'); 
  alert(img); 
});
```